# Disable swipe left/right feature of Pivot in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, pivot

I want to cover my pivot with ScrollViewer but it does not effect because pivot has it scrollviewer itself. So I want to know the way to disable swipe left/right to change tab of Pivot.

Note: cannot use `IsHitTestVisible="True"` because it will disable all interaction of Pivot include tap on header to change tab

Comment: So why are you using the Pivot control itself? You can use StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal" in a ScrollViewer.

Comment: I'm maintaining the project that using it, man. If I change the layout it will cost time.

Comment: Check this MSDN answer if it helps : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/59986d8e-e83e-450f-ae96-262236442c4a/uwp-how-to-disable-swipe-leftright-on-pivot-to-get-a-more-tablike-experience?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: checked, doesn't work. it will disable all action inside pivot.

Comment: Check this locable pivot class : https://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/Pivot/LockablePivot.cs

Comment: can we use it in UWP

Comment: It is nothing but an extended Pivot class. So if you can use Pivot in UWP then you should be able to use locable class as well. This is my take on this but I have never worked on UWP. I think this worths a try at least !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Disable Left/Right Swipe on Pivot but still want to navigate to Different Pivot Items when Header is tapped, You need to Disable `HorizontalScrollMode` on `ScrollViewer` on the Pivot when Pointer is `PointerEntered` or `PointerMoved`

To Do this first We need to Gain Access to `ScrollViewer` Inside `Pivot`. To do this, I used a Helper Method that I copied from one of the answers from SO.

```
public static T FindChildByName<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (parent == null) return null;
    T foundChild = null;
    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
            foundChild = FindChildByName<T>(child, childName);
            if (foundChild != null) break;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
        {
            var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
            if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
            {
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundChild;
}
```

Now in `Pivot`, Activate Event `Pivot_Loaded` and your `Pivot_Loaded` should show something like below.

```
private void Pivot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Pivot pivot = sender as Pivot;
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(pivot);
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindChildByName<ScrollViewer>(pivot, "ScrollViewer");
    scrollViewer.PointerEntered += (s, a) => { ((ScrollViewer)s).HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled; };
    scrollViewer.PointerMoved += (s, a) => { ((ScrollViewer)s).HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled; };
    scrollViewer.PointerExited += (s, a) => { ((ScrollViewer)s).HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled; };
    scrollViewer.PointerReleased += (s, a) => { ((ScrollViewer)s).HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled; };
    scrollViewer.PointerCaptureLost += (s, a) => { ((ScrollViewer)s).HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled; };
}
```

The whole idea of doing this is from this [blog](http://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2015/12/30/disable-gestures-on-pivot-control/) post.

Good Luck.

Comment: @Bui Quang Huy, did this reply resolved your issue? Did you have any updates?

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy? Any Update?

Comment: I'm sorry for replying late but I ignored this issue. BTW, I used some trick that is Disable Pivot interaction when mouse wheeling to enable scroll and when mouse move, I enable it again. :)

Comment: It's OnPointerWheelChanged event and PointerMoved event with IsHitTestVisible = false and vice versa.